# ES6 returning destructed function argument

Tags: javascript, object, ecmascript-6, destructuring

I have an object with multiple properties like so

```js
const someObject = {
  id: 'someid',
  name: 'somename',
  age: 'somenumber',
  someproperty: 'xxx',
  anotherproperty: 'yyy',
  foo: 'bar',
  // ... with many more object properties
}
```

I have a selector function, with `someObject` being the input argument, which returns only a few properties of this object.

```js
const functionName = ({id, age, name, foo}) => ({id, age, name, foo});
```

Is it possible to return destructed argument directly, without the need of repetetive code?

Destructing with `...rest` (and then returning rest) is probably bad option since I have way more object properties that I do not want to return than properties that I need.

Comment: Well you can exclude `const functionName = ({someproperty, anotherproperty, ...whatYouWant})  => whatYouWant` still not the best